# What is wrong with my Web API routing?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a single controller with the two following action signatures. I'm using convetional vs. attribute routing because I've been trying anything to make this work, and conventional removed 1 of 2 problems.

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<EmployeeBindingModel>))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ReadAll()
```

When I call this from Postman with the URL: `http://localhost:53093/api/Employees/ReadAll` I get the following JSON back:

```
{
  "Message": "The request is invalid.",
  "MessageDetail": "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult] Read(Int32)' in 'AcmeSoft.WebApi.Controllers.EmployeesController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."
}
```

The other action is:

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(EmployeeBindingModel))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Read(int id)
```

and when I call it with this URL: `http://localhost:53093/api/Employees/Read/5` I get the expected employee JSON record back.

My routing is set up as follows in `WebApiConfig`:

```
//config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});
```

I've always used this standard boilerplate, and today is the first time I get the error. Why on Earth would an action without a parameter expect one? `ReadAll` has never had a parameter, so it's not even some ghost. I've deleted all ASP.NET Temporary files with no change.

Comment: Include the controller to complete the example. Right now we can assume it is employee controller but that would still be a guess.

Comment: @Nkosi I All that affects routing in the controller is the action method signature and its attributes, and they are included.

Comment: You are using convention-based routing and have two `HttpGet` actions in the controller. Based on the web API config shown they should not be working as they will conflict with each other. So that means that there are details that have been omitted from the question which could be used to better assess your problem and provide a solution. Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `Why on Earth would an action without a parameter expect one?` The routing table grabs the first route that matches the request made. If there are multiple routes that match then there can be a conflict of the request was matched to the wrong route.

Comment: @Nkosi, if you can explain what, without any redirects, how the action implementations affect the routing, I take my hat off to you. Ankush's answer below has solved the problem with only the necessary details I provided. Is Ankush psychic or something? If anything relevant is missing, it's how I'm calling the api and what request verb I'm using, which is GET.

Comment: No he is not. His answer is correct in this instance. What he did not explain is why his answer worked and why your route failed. If you are satisfied with just getting the code that stops your problem with no clue as to what actually caused the problem and how to avoid making the same mistake again then who am I to get involved. My apologies.

Comment: @Nkosi It's obvious that his code has an `{action}` parameter where the *standard* code generated by the Web API project template doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make change in WebApiConfig:

```
//config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});
```

**Use action also in routeTemplate**

Comment: The nail of the head! I assume that the action invocation selected the first `HttpGet` action it could match, the one with the `id`, for the successful call, but baulked at the other `HttpGet` action with no defining parameter, or something like that. This makes me wonder why the default route template ommits `{action}`. Are we only supposed to have one action for each request verb, and the action is selected based on that?

Comment: @ProfK Yes. the default convention-based route template was originally meant for RESTful Web API with one action per HTTP method. The framework still allows the flexibility of changing it to suit your particular needs.

Comment: Thanks, @Nkosi. That does seem a bit limiting, but it's probably one of those things that got left behind with the new Attribute Routing and Core Web APIs.